# Validation of viewstate MAC failed for wordpress

Tags: asp.net, windows, wordpress, viewstate

We have a wordpress site on a linux share server (using cPanel). we want to create a login script to connect our site to another link that is using a microsoft server (aspx page). When we use the script and try to login we see the following error:

Server Error in '/NET' Application.

Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that  configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=314055

We did some checks and it seems this problem can be solved by editing the web.config file on a windows server but ours is linux. Can anyone suggest how to resolve the issue on the wordpress?

Here is how we used the code in wordpress:

```
<form method="post" action="http://owners.mydomain.com/login.aspx" id="ddl00"> 
<div class="aspNetHidden"> 
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE"      value="/fdfdfaerghjkkaaklgjlakrrvc34fdfWjAdfdfdfamNIzDfdf6adBjuDFWfzdfmdffY" /> 
</div> 

<div class="aspNetHidden"> 

<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/dfdfdasfasdfjglakfJKLFJDLKJR34252KKJLKJFD/fdfkadfeoawrfir/IeirIIURIR+KKJFKEjkdsfjerk" /> 
</div> 
<table style="width:auto; margin:2em auto 0 auto;"> 
<tr> 
<td class="label"> 
Username
</td> 
<td> 
<input name="username" type="text" id="username" tabindex="1" /> 
</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td class="label"> 
Password 
</td> 
<td> 
<input name="password" type="password" id="password" tabindex="2" /> 
</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td colspan="2" class="button_row"> 
<input type="submit" name="ctl15" value="Login" tabindex="3" /> 
</td> 
</tr> 
</table> 
</form>
```

Comment: Can you show how are you making the login from your WordPress site to the ASP.NET application?

Comment: I have added that to the question.

Answer (score 1):

In your form in WordPress you have two hidden fields, the `__VIEWSTATE` and the `__EVENTVALIDATION` whom values you have copied.

These values are auto generated and are used from the ASP.NET engine to validate each receiving request.

The values you are using have expired and **it is expected that you will get this error**.

You need to adjust the ASP.NET application, if you have access to it so that it can receive a POST from other applications. I am thinking of an empty page (e.g. `external-login.aspx`) that will accept these POSTS and checks the credentials.

An example:

Web form in WordPress site

```
<form method="post" action="http://owners.mydomain.com/external-login.aspx"> 
    <table style="width:auto; margin:2em auto 0 auto;"> 
        <tr> 
            <td class="label"> 
                Username
            </td> 
            <td> 
                <input name="username" type="text" id="username" tabindex="1" /> 
            </td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td class="label"> 
                Password 
            </td> 
            <td> 
                <input name="password" type="password" id="password" tabindex="2" /> 
            </td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td colspan="2" class="button_row"> 
                <input type="submit" name="ctl15" value="Login" tabindex="3" /> 
            </td> 
        </tr> 
    </table> 
</form>
```

Code in external-login.aspx

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string username = Request.Form["username"];
    string password = Request.Form["password"];

    //Code here that checks the credentials and logins the user
}
```